# Delete all the records under specif column names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-delete

I have a table in MySQL Workbench that looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to delete all the records under columns C, D and E.
So after my statement I want my table to look like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Please consider sharing the schema of the tables as well. And on what basis are you willing to delete the data for those fields?

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH I'm deleting them because I need to update the table with python. My aim is to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I f you mantain the value in column A but clear content for  the column B,C,D,E You need  update
For all the rows  you can use

```
update my_table  
set B = NULL  
, C = NULL
, D = NULL 
, E = NULL
```

or if you want update only the row with A IN (1,6,11)

```
update my_table  
set B = NULL  
, C = NULL
, D = NULL 
, E = NULL 
WHERE A IN (1,6,11)
```

Comment: this works perfectly in MySQL. Short other question, now I want to do the same statement via Python. How do I set the brackets and the quotation marks?

Comment: @Premier12  i'm not in pyton  ..  but you could try serching in SO for this.   i guess there are  some answer  for this